# Is it possible to make a systemd unit wait until all its Conflicts= are stopped before trying to start?

Tags: systemd

I have a series of mutually exclusive systemd services that are started and stopped by users as needed. Each of the services requires exclusive use of some hardware, so many of the services conflict with each other. (But not all services conflict with all other services)

To manage this I've used Conflicts=, which almost works perfectly, however the ExecStart of the starting service seems to run while the ExecStop script of the conflicting service is still running running, which causes the starting service to fail as the hardware resources are not yet available.

If I have the start scripts sleep for some safe amount of time, like 30 seconds, they function perfectly, but I'd much rather them start as soon as the conflicting service stops.

After= doesn't seem to work as the services can be stopped and started repeatedly, in arbitrary order, and After= causes a cyclical dependency.

Is there a way to do this in systemd without resorting to checking if a conflict is running inside the ExecStart scripts?

Answer (score 4):

The manual page `systemd.unit(5)` has [this to say about `Conflicts=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Conflicts=):

> Note that this setting does not imply an ordering dependency, similarly to the `Wants=` and `Requires=` dependencies described above. This means that to ensure that the conflicting unit is stopped before the other unit is started, an `After=` or `Before=` dependency must be declared. It doesn't matter which of the two ordering dependencies is used, because stop jobs are always ordered before start jobs, see the discussion in `Before=`/`After=` below.

In other words, just declare an ordering dependency.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your `ExecStop=` command is issuing an async operation, like sending a termination signal to a process, and then exiting immediately before the process has finished shutting down.

Make sure your `ExecStop=` command is a synchronous operation that does not exit until the service is completely shutdown.

Comment: That was how I expected it to work, so the ExecStop command uses a do while to wait until the service is stopped before it returns, and I have confirmed that the the units don't get marked as stopped until after the ExecStop script finishes freeing up the resources. The ExecStart is definitely running while the ExecStops are still waiting, and the service failed to start messages appear in the journal before the service stopped messages.

Comment: I would search the [systemd issue tracker](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues) for bug reports about this and if there is not already one, file a new one. (Assuming you are using the latest version of systemd or nearly-so). Your experience seems to be in conflict with [documentation for ExecStop=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStop=), which I based my answer on.

Answer (score 0):

If your process is of `Type=exec`, you can use the following to wait for it to terminate after it is requested to terminate: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/13284#issuecomment-784556633

```
[Service]
# Type must be set correctly for $MAINPID detection to work
Type=exec
ExecStart=/path/to/myservice/start-command
ExecStop=/path/to/myservice/stop-command
ExecStop=/usr/bin/sh -c 'while kill -0 $MAINPID 2>/dev/null; do sleep 1; done'
TimeoutStopSec=15
```

Comment: As an alternative to a shell loop with a sleep in the middle, you can use `/usr/bin/tail --pid $MAINPID -f /dev/null`. `tail` will exit as soon as the specified PID has terminated.