# How to set a conflict in systemd in one direction only

Tags: systemd

I have two systemd services `A` (takes a few minutes) and `B` (only very few seconds):

- `A` has a high priority and must run under all circumstances.
- `B` cannot be started when `A` runs, but there is no problem to start `A` when `B` still runs. It is even desired to start `A` even when `B` still runs, as `A` must run under all circumstances.
- `B` shouldn't be killed when `Conflicts=` stops the service, instead it should still finish running.

The [systemd man](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) tells me:

> Configures negative requirement dependencies. If a unit has a Conflicts= setting on another unit, starting the former will stop the latter **and vice versa**.

I thought using `Conflicts=A.service` might be the solution. The man tells me that starting `A` will stop `B`, but also what I don't want is `B` will stop `A`.

Is there a way to have `Conflicts=` just unidirectional?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Conflict=` directive is not really what you want, not only because it works in both directions, but also because you don't want to stop the currently running `B.service` (if one is running) when `A.service` starts.

The way I'd recommend you implement this is by adding an additional script to `B.service` that would check whether `A.service` is running and then prevent `B.service` from starting in that case.

You can do that by adding an `ExecStartPre=` to `B.service` that exits with a non-zero status, which will prevent it from going further in its startup.

My suggestion would be to add something like this to your existing `/etc/systemd/system/B.service`:

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c 'if systemctl -q is-active A.service; then \
                             echo "A.service already running, will not start B.service"; \
                             exit 75; \
                         fi'
```

This uses [`systemctl is-active`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#is-active%20PATTERN%E2%80%A6) to check whether service `A.service` is currently running.

If it doesn't, it echoes a message (which will end up in the journal and, more importantly, shown whenver you check `systemctl status B.service`.) Additionally, it will exit with a non-zero status. I picked exit code 75 since systemd will show that as `EX_TEMPFAIL` which means "Temporary failure; user is invited to retry."  See [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Process%20exit%20codes) for how systemd interprets/names process exit codes.

Line wrapping is optional too, you can simply write everyting in a single line, just omitting the trailing `\` used to wrap them.

Comment: Perfect! This is indeed a neat solution. Even with a good exit code ;) Thanks!

Comment: Wow `systemctl -q is-active` doesn't work with `Type=oneshot` services. Well, but there is an easy work around, just need to change the first line to: `if systemctl is-active A.service | grep activating; then`.

Comment: @Wuff `Type=oneshot` contradicts this method. It has a live-span of basically zero.

Comment: Thank you for the work-around!  It seems like a very useful directive to me -- say `InhibitedBy`. E.g. you have a `.timer` that should not run when specific `.service`-files are on-going.

Comment: I found that simply using `After=` was sufficient for my use case. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/562959/22666